# How to write a file to external storage?

Tags: android, encryption, android-file

I tried to encrypt and save a file to the same location in the external storage with a different file name. But the way I have used is seems like wrong. Please help someone.

```
       public static void encrypt(SecretKey secretKey, String filePath, IvParameterSpec iv){
    try {

        String file = "";
        // Here you read the cleartext.
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        // This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by another stream.
        //String filePath2 = filePath+"enc";

        file = filePath.substring(0,filePath.length()-5)+"enc.jpeg";

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Log.i(TAG, "Uri = "+file);

        // Create cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }

        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(NoSuchPaddingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(InvalidKeyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }/*catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
}
```

Manifest file containing both read and write permissions.

Comment: What filepath are you passing to this method ?

Comment: `to the same location in the external storage` ?????

Comment: You write to a file in the same way to all locations. So what is the problem?

Comment: And what goes wrong? Errors? Exceptions? Show full path.

Comment: @greenapps I tried to write the encrypted file to the same folder but it's not working

Comment: @greenapps /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.browser/files/Download/2016-07-05-12-33-40-1614210048enc.jpeg this is the full path

Comment: `to write the encrypted file to the same folder`. You still did not tell what you mean with 'the same folder'. `com.android.browser`. That is not your app is it? You should explain much more.

Comment: @greenapps same folder means here I'm trying to encrypt a file located in the downloads folder and after encrypting I need to save that encrypted file in the same folder which means downloads with a different name. Hope you got it

Comment: But what goes wrong? You still did not tell!

Answer (score 1):

You specify "AES/ECB/NoPadding".

With ECB there is no iv and thus no need to supply one on calling the `encrypt` method. ECB mode is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

AES is a block cipher and as such it encrypts block sized portions at a time thus the input needs to be a multiple of the block size. Padding accomplished this transparently but you have specified "NoPadding" so the input file size ,just be an exact multiple of the block size, for AES that is 16-bytes. Instead use PKCS#7 (some tined referred to as PKCS#5) padding.

The simplest solution is to use a library that puts all the elements of secure encryption together including password derivation, a random iv, padding, encryption authentication. Consider [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), it provides all of this plus versioning. See [RNCryptor README](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/blob/master/README.md) and [RNCryptor-Spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but here um worrying about the saving the file not about the padding

Comment: AES is a block cipher, the input **must** be a multiple of the block size for ECB, CBC and other modes. So either worry about padding or hope to get lucky, your choice.